# check whether test function will run in parallel

Tags: go, testing

How can I check whether a `*testing.T` has been set to run in parallel?

Ideally the solution might be:

```
func isParellelT(t *testing.T) bool {
   // return some means to figure t has called t.Parallel().
}
```

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: You can’t. Rather than conditionally check for a parallel test, why not conditionally set `t.Parallel()`?

Comment: @JimB I want to check if a test method if parallelised to know whether it's okay to update some shared metadata value from a test helper.

Comment: This would be to avoid a refactor to manage and allow for multiple copies of this value - I'd consider this too risky for our codebase.

Comment: I would consider adding a flag to run parallel tests less risky than inspecting the un-exported test internals.

Comment: Yeah, even adding a flag would not an ideal as most of the tests rely on these metadata values, kept at a default value. For now, I think it's easier just to assume the function which updates metadata values will be used correctly (not called by parallelised test functions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`testing.T` does not make this information available. Your tests should not depend on it. If you want to do this, you almost certainly should do something else instead.

However, it is possible to access the private data using reflection, or derive it by checking whether `testing.T.SetEnv` panics :

```golang
package para

import (
    "reflect"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func TestParallelTrue(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()

    if !isParallel(t) {
        t.Errorf("isParallel: got = false; want = true")
    }
    if !isParallel2(t) {
        t.Errorf("isParallel2: got = false; want = true")
    }
}

func TestParallelFalse(t *testing.T) {
    if isParallel(t) {
        t.Errorf("isParallel: got = true; want = false")
    }
    if isParallel2(t) {
        t.Errorf("isParallel2: got = true; want = false")
    }
}

// WARNING: This is terrible and should never be used.
// It will likely break on old or future versions of Go.
func isParallel(t *testing.T) (b bool) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(t).Elem()

    // Check testing.T.isParallel first.
    isPara := v.FieldByName("isParallel")
    if isPara.IsValid() {
        return isPara.Bool()
    }

    // Otherwise try testing.T.common.isParallel.
    common := v.FieldByName("common")
    if !common.IsValid() {
        t.Fatal("isParallel: unsupported testing.T implementation")
    }

    isPara = common.FieldByName("isParallel")
    if !isPara.IsValid() {
        t.Fatal("isParallel: unsupported testing.T implementation")
    }

    return isPara.Bool()
}

// WARNING: This is terrible and should never be used.
// Requires Go1.17+.
func isParallel2(t *testing.T) (b bool) {
    defer func() {
        v := recover()
        if v == nil {
            return
        }
        if s, ok := v.(string); ok && strings.Contains(s, "parallel tests") {
            b = true
            return
        }
        panic(v)
    }()
    t.Setenv("_dummy", "value")
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mpx, I hadn't thought about reflect to inspect the internal fields. It would be great if they could provide the value through the interface, although even to me it seems to be a rare case you need to inspect whether a test case is parallel or not.

Comment: You could just explaining why it's needed on the Issue tracker with a proposal to add "IsParallel() bool" or similar.  However, I suspect the general recommendation would be to refactor to avoid the need (may be considered a code smell).